How to connect two devices via i2c?
I am working with 2 Pololu Altimu-10 V6 connected to the same ESP32 board. Both of them are connected via i2c protocol and have different addresses. The addresses are 0x1C and 0x1E.
I have this code to calibrate the magnetometer of one. How can I change it to measure both of them?
I don't know how to specify the address of each one.
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LIS3MDL.h>

LIS3MDL mag;
LIS3MDL::vector<int16_t> running_min = {32767, 32767, 32767}, running_max = {-32768, -32768, -32768};

char report[80];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

  if (!mag.init()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to detect and initialize magnetometer!");
    while (1);
  }

  mag.enableDefault();
}

void loop() {
  mag.read();

  running_min.x = min(running_min.x, mag.m.x);
  running_min.y = min(running_min.y, mag.m.y);
  running_min.z = min(running_min.z, mag.m.z);

  running_max.x = max(running_max.x, mag.m.x);
  running_max.y = max(running_max.y, mag.m.y);
  running_max.z = max(running_max.z, mag.m.z);

  snprintf(report, sizeof(report), "min: {%+6d, %+6d, %+6d}   max: {%+6d, %+6d, %+6d}",
    running_min.x, running_min.y, running_min.z,
    running_max.x, running_max.y, running_max.z);
  Serial.println(report);

  delay(100);
}


I guess you are using this library from pololu. In the Readme file under "Library reference" you can find the following entry:

`bool init(deviceType device, sa0State sa0)
Initializes the library with the device being used (device_LIS3MDL or device_auto) and the state of the SA1 pin (sa1_low, sa1_high, or sa1_auto), which determines the second-least significant bit of the I²C slave address. Constants for these arguments are defined in LIS3MDL.h. Both of these arguments are optional; if they are not specified, the library will try to automatically detect the device address. A boolean is returned indicating whether the type of device was successfully determined (if necessary).

I'm interpreting this as the following: You can create 2 LIS3MDL objects like this:
LIS3MDL mag1;
LIS3MDL mag2;

Then in setup() you init both of them, but providing the optional parameters of the init function:
if(!mag1.init(LIS3MDL::device_LIS3MDL, LIS3MDL::sa1_low)){
  Serial.println("Failed to detect and initialize magnetometer 1!");
  while (1);
}
if(!mag2.init(LIS3MDL::device_LIS3MDL, LIS3MDL::sa1_high)){
  Serial.println("Failed to detect and initialize magnetometer 2!");
  while (1);
}

The first parameter is the device type. It would probably also work with the value LIS3MDL::device_auto, though just setting it makes it more explicit. The second parameter represents the state of the address pin (SA1) on the corresponding module. In the above code the module, whose SA1 pin is at LOW, will be mag1; the one with SA1 pin HIGH will be mag2. Note, that you of course need to actually connect the SA1 pins of the modules to ground/Vcc respectively for this to work.
Then everything, that you previously did with only one LIS3MDL object, you can do with each of these two LIS3MDL objects consecutively.

I tried but I got this error: 'device_LIS3MDL' was not declared in this scope.

@hcheung If I use mag1.init(0x1C) I have this error: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'LIS3MDL::deviceType'. Also I tried in binary (as in the documentation) mag1.init(0b0011110)  and the error was the same.

@sonlas10 Sorry, had not seen, how exactly that is defined. It is actually an enum inside of the class. The documentation does not mention this. I could compile when adding LIS3MDL:: in front of the names device_LIS3MDL and sa1_high/sa1_low. That tells the compiler, that this is a member of the class LIS3MDL

@sonlas10, my apology, i re-read the source code in more detail, I was wrong. Maybe you should consider to raise an issue at the library GitHub.
